# How to detect Ctrl key press when mouse is positioned over element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple Grid that drags and drops items. What I want to do is when the mouse is positioned on the draggable icon, when the user presses the Ctrl key to be able to detect it and console.log(true). My attempt currently doesn't work as expected for some reason the console.log detects only the first time CTRL is being pressed, how can I successfully keep track if Ctrl is being pressed when the mouse cursor is on the draggable icon? Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Grid, GridColumn as Column } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
import { DragAndDrop } from '@progress/kendo-react-common';
import { DraggableRow } from './draggable-row';
import { Checkbox } from '@progress/kendo-react-inputs';
import { DragHandleCell } from './drag-handle-cell';
import products from './products.json';
import {
  groupBy,
  GroupDescriptor,
  GroupResult,
} from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { groupBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';

export const ReorderContext = React.createContext({
  reorder: () => {},
  dragStart: () => {},
});

const App = () => {
  const [gridData, setGridData] = React.useState(products);
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = React.useState(null);
  const [ctrlOn, setCtrl] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ((e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) && e.code === 'KeyC') {
        setCtrl(true);
      }
    });
    console.log(ctrlOn);
  });

  const highlightCol = (e) => {
    if (e.ctrlOn) {
      console.log('');
    }
  };
  const reorder = (dataItem, direction) => {
    if (activeItem === dataItem) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(activeItem);

    let reorderedData = gridData.slice();
    let prevIndex = reorderedData.findIndex((p) => p === activeItem);
    let nextIndex = reorderedData.findIndex((p) => p === dataItem);
    reorderedData.splice(prevIndex, 1);
    reorderedData.splice(
      Math.max(nextIndex + (direction === 'before' ? -1 : 0), 0),
      0,
      activeItem || reorderedData[0]
    );
    setGridData(reorderedData);

    console.log(activeItem);
  };

  const dragStart = (dataItem) => {
    setActiveItem(dataItem);
  };

  return (
    <ReorderContext.Provider
      value={{
        reorder: reorder,
        dragStart: dragStart,
      }}
    >
      <DragAndDrop>
        <Grid
          style={{
            height: '400px',
          }}
          data={gridData}
          dataItemKey={'ProductID'}
          rowRender={(row, rowProps) => (
            <DraggableRow elementProps={row.props} {...rowProps} />
          )}
        >
          <Column
            title=""
            width="80px"
            cell={DragHandleCell}
            onClick={highlightCol}
          />
          {/* <Column title="" width="80px" cell={CustomCell} /> */}
          <Column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="60px" />
          <Column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="250px" />
          <Column field="Category.CategoryName" title="CategoryName" />
          <Column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" width="80px" />
          <Column field="UnitsInStock" title="In stock" width="80px" />
        </Grid>
      </DragAndDrop>
    </ReorderContext.Provider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('my-app'));
```

and here is a reproducible example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cv2hnu-lj18m8?file=app/main.jsx

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/utils/api/NormalizedDragEvent/ they include the modifier key state in the event payload. No reason to be adding your own listener for it.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your useEffect only runs once (no dependency array) thus you only console log once. Put the console log inside of the event listener

Modify like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.ctrlKey) {
        console.log('CTRL - highlight row');
      }
    });
  });
```

Still a lot of things to handle tho, e.g.: You should store the hovered draggable's row in a state (with onMouseEnter / onMouseLeave), and if there is an element in that state, that means the user is hovers over a draggable -> in this case ctrl should highlight.

I hope I could help